# FME - Load shapefile to SDE table

Tags: fme-form

I have shapefile which contain polygon features. I open this file as a reader. I need to load their data in to SDE table.

The problem is ObjectId and shape columns are not listed in user attributes for reader and unable to match with writer attributes

Answer (score 4):

Those columns cannot be manipulated by user or fme.
They are internal managed by esri and so will be written by sde.

Comment: I agree with Brad - see http://fmepedia.safe.com/AnswersQuestionDetail?id=906a0000000ce2xAAA

Comment: It depends if the user creates the layer with SDELAYER or with FME Desktop.

Comment: never heard of that. can you explain?